# How to print first 100 character in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to print first 100 character of string in django.

```
{% if dt.faq_info|length < 100 %}
    {{dt.faq_info}}
{% else %}
    {{dt.faq_info[:100]}}
{% endif %}
```

But I recieved `TemplateSyntaxError`

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[:100]' from 'dt.faq_info[:100]'
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [`truncatechars`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) built-in template filter:

```
{{ dt.faq_info | truncatechars:100 }}
```

If you really want to use string slicing you should use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% else %}
    {{ dt.faq_info | slice:":100" }}
```